# Too many USB2.0 headers?

Tags: usb

My case has 3 USB2.0 headers on the inside, but my motherboard only has 2 plugs for them. I'm confused because the motherboard says it handles 4 USB2.0 ports on the front (which is what it has) but I don't know if they'll work if I don't plug one of them in. What do I do?

Comment: Yes, Your motherboard has 4 USB 2.0 ports, that doesn't mean it has 4 headers.  You can only connect 2 of the 3 USB 2.0 headers on your case.  The third one will either have to remain disconnected or you will have to purchase a PCI-E USB 2.0 card to support it.

Comment: @Burgi - What does?  I assume we are talking about the 9-pin USB 2.0 header.  The motherboard has 1 HUB due to the I/O shield, and 2 additional Hubs (I would assume) due to the 2 9-pin headers.  I cannot do any research because zero information was provided about the motherboard.

Comment: What model of motherboard? What model of case?

Answer (score 2):

Each internal USB header carries two USB ports.

So on a case with four USB ports you would expect two USB header plugs but you say your case has three, there are several possible explanations of this.

1. Your case has built-in functionality like a media card reader or a small display or fancy monitoring stuff that uses USB and one of the header plugs relates to this functionality.
2. Your case has more USB ports than you think it does (sometimes ports are hidden)
3. You have misidentified another connector plug as a USB one. Firewire and front panel audio use the same size header connectors as USB but are NOT interchangable with it.

So anyway lets assume you really do have three USB 2.0 connections from your case but only two connectors on your motherboard what are your options?

1. Leave one of them disconnected. If you do this then most likely something won't work, either front USB ports or a feature built into the case (media card reader etc).
2. If your motherboard has a USB 3 header that you aren't using then you can get adapters to turn that into a USB 2 header. For example http://www.miniinthebox.com/usb-3-0-20-pin-housing-female-to-usb-2-0-9-pin-motherboard-male-cable-converter-adapter-cable_p3381349.html
3. Install a card that provides an additional internal USB header. For example the Startech PCIUSB7.
4. Install an internal hub that takes a single internal USB header and splits it to multiple such headers. For example the NZXT IU01.